# Read data from Elasticsearch with scala and spark 3.0.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, hadoop

I'm trying to migrate from Spark-2.4.6 to 3.0.1, but it seems that es-hadoop does not have support for Spark 3.0+. Do you have any solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately an ElasticSearch connector that supports Apache Spark 3.0 is not available yet. a work around can be done as , Spark 3.0.0 relies on Scala 2.12, which is not yet supported by Elasticsearch-hadoop. This and a few further issues prevent us using Spark 3.0.0 together with Elasticsearch. If you want to compile it yourself, there is a pull-request on elasticsearch-hadoop (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/pull/1308) which should at least allow using scala 2.12. Not sure if it will fix the other issues as well.